# How to write unit test cases of application which is using two different database?

Tags: unit-testing

I have a application which is using two different database for replication. I want to write test cases for this application.

I can not used Mock framework as it is not using interfaces. We need to check that If there is record in one database table and application run then it should move records to other database. We also want that after execution values should not be saved in database. Operation should be rolled back after test case is complete.

Comment: That is an integration test, not unit test.

Comment: @Nkosi is right, unit tests should never go past a certain scope (the unit, generally a class). In other words, you shouldn't touch the DB - that's already system (integration testing).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's much too broad for Stack Overflow.  It might be more suited to [softwareengineering.se].

Answer (score 0):

From how you phrase your question it is not quite clear if the tests you want to perform are unit-tests or integration-tests.  The distinction is not so much on whether or not you isolate your code, but rather what the goal of the test is.

Assumption A: Your test goal is to test the logic of your own code.  The dependency on the data bases is a nuisance, and you would rather have your code isolated from the data bases.  The access to the data bases, however, is not via interfaces (in the sense of a programming language construct), but goes to the data base APIs directly, possibly even to global instances of the data bases.  And, you have not the possibility to change the code.

Depending on the programming language and environment you use there may be other ways to replace the data bases with mocks, stubs or whatever: For example, you don't need to link against the original data base lib.  Instead, you can create a mocked data base lib to link against ("linker seam") which you can control from your test code.  Or, you could replace calls to the db with the help of the preprocessor (in C or C++) to, again, a mocked implementation.

Assumption B: Your test goal is to ensure that the interaction between your code and the two data bases works as expected.  For example, you want to be sure that the elements are truly transferred from the one data base to the other.

This would be an integration test scenario, and mocking the data bases would not be a useful step here, for the following reason: If you made wrong assumptions how to interact with the data base, the mocks you create only again reflect your wrong assumptions.

Your problem under assumption B is more how you can ensure that each test case starts and exits with a clean state.  How to achieve this is hard to judge from the little information you provided.  You could work with backups of the data base to do the rollback etc., but the options depend a lot on your specific situation.